# Is this a case of multiple-test?

Tags: t-test

I had a different view with a friend on whether we need an adjustment of p.values for multiple tests. Here is the case, we have a compositional data set with $n=1000$ subjects and $m=26$ continuous variables ($\sum_{m=1}^{26}y_i=100$) from two geographical sites say A  and B ($n_A=n_B=500$). Then I did t.test between two sites for each of the 26 variables and provided the p.values. I thought there are not necessary to adjust these 26 p.values to claim significant between two sites because for each variable it's just tested one time, while my friend thought you did 26 tests and they are not independent and we have to do a bonferroni correction, namely a threshold of $0.05/26=0.002$ should be applied. So, I would like to know whether we need the correct on this case.

Comment: Concept of multiple-test is, doing multiple tests between multiple samples for same set of variables. This case is not an instance of it. Although it looks somewhat counter intuitive, as you increase number of tests there is a good chance that some of them will give significant results by chance. But this is what type I error means. When doing a single test, that type I error probability is also present.

Comment: @Macond – I disagree. The example states that  26 variables are measured for 1000 subjects. Independence or not of the variables is irrelevant. What is relevant is that we are carrying out a family of 26 tests and we want to protect against false positives. A single t-test at $\alpha=0.05$ will result in a false positive 5% of the time. On the other hand, if I do 26 tests at the $\alpha=0.05$ then this family of tests will result in – on average - 26*0.05 > 1 false positive by chance alone. Corrections for multiple testing protect a family of tests against at least one false positive occurring

Comment: @DavidZ A less conservative correction method is advised, eg Holm-Bonferroni

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a classic case where you need to correct for multiple testing. It is irrelevant whether the tests are independent or not. If you are testing at say $\alpha$=0.05 then you have a 5% chance of a false positive by chance alone. 26 tests at this level will give ~1 false positive by chance. Bonferroni will protect against such error but it is very cconservative. You are better off using a less conservative multiple correction approach.